# Scroll doesn't work properly on using a inverted FlatList in react native

Tags: android, react-native

If I use a FlatList with invert prop, I am unable to scroll through list. To be precise I can't use the fling gesture, and can drag the list to make it scroll which is annoying. I am using React Native 0.56.0 on Android P.

Here's my code snippet for FlatList

```
<FlatList data={this.state.data} inverted={true} renderItem ={({item})=> <Text>{item.key}</Text>} />
```

[Here's a recording of screen for better understanding of the issue.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Iy6ndq_3R3mHuhCWMX-m2bjxVSbJIrHy/view?usp=drivesdk)